# Repositioning windows working well, but not gnome-terminal

Tags: xdotool

I have set up a few keyboard shortcuts to reposition windows to the corners of the screen, using xdotool. For example, to move a window top-left I use
`xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0`

Bottom and right are fixed simply by using large numbers. This all works very well, with one exception: gnome-terminal.

For some reason, gnome-terminal does NOT honour the 'left' position, but is offset by maybe 25 pixels on my screen. The screenshot shows what SHOULD have been gnome-terminal top-left.

[image]

Ubuntu 20.04 BTW...

Anyone?

Comment: It are the windows with GTK3 client side decoration that do not behave properly.